# ionic what's app chat error : login with facebook is not working

Tags: facebook, mongodb, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am new to ionic app, currently working on whatsapp like chat.

In the server I started the app.js and it shows connected to mongodb.

In the client I ran ionic serve and open the url in the browser. But when I click on login with facebook nothing happens. In the console I see the following errors

> Attempt local load:  ​​
>   :8100/#/login:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myip:5984/registeruser/?_nonce=1479196427607. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://myip:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
>
> app.js:47 Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined(…)

**edit**

cordova is linked as

```
<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Comment: Enable CORS at server side and make sure you loaded cordova js

Comment: @Sa E Chowdary crodova is linked, still shows the error

Answer (score 0):

add this plug in to your google chrome

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

after installing enable the cors in browser and run your project.